# Tuple unpacking inside map

Tags: scala

I would like to unpack tuples inside `map` to access some of the values.

In Python I would do it this way:

```
>>> [topic for topic, partition in [('x', 1), ('y', 2)]]
['x', 'y']
```

Here tuples `('x', 1), ('y', 2)` are unpacked into `topic, partition`, and then I access `topic`.

In Scala I have only managed to make it this way:

```
List(('x', 1), ('y', 2)).map(_._1)
```

But I would like to have explicit unpack into tuple as an itermediate step (even if it introduces some overhead) as I think it makes the code more readable.

I would like to achieve something like

```
List(('x', 1), ('y', 2)).map((topic, partition) => topic)
```

Unfortunatelly it didn't work:

```
> <console>:9: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
                List(('x', 1), ('y', 2)).map((topic, partition) => topic)
```

Other attempts (e.g. `List(('x', 1), ('y', 2)).map(Tuple2(topic, partition) => topic)`) also failed.

Is there any way to achieve something similar to what I have in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
List(('x', 1), ('y', 2)).map {
  case (topic, partition) => topic
}
```

**Edit**: one more way to do the same, as @senia suggested:

```
for { 
  (topic, partition) <- List(('x', 1), ('y', 2)) 
} yield topic
```

Comment: Yup! Adding the magic `case` keyword is key, though there's been a recent groundswell of interest to remove this requirement.

Comment: You could also add `for { (topic, partition) <- List(('x', 1), ('y', 2)) } yield topic` to your answer.

Comment: Also mention that 2.11 tells you, Consider a pattern matching anoynmous function, `{ case (topic, partition) =>  ... }`  Eerily helpful.

Comment: @KevinWright Can you give a link to a discussion about this?